# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-application-gateway

I have configured an Application Gateway (AG) to do SSL termination/offload. The AG is configured to only listen on port 443 for HTTPS connections. Is it possible to redirect HTTP to HTTPS without having to:

- Create a new VM that contains a webserver that redirects the traffic and configure AG to listen on port 80 with the new VM in its backend pool, or
- Also allow HTTP connections to my application VM's and handle redirect in my application code

I'm hoping I overlooked a flag/feature in AG.

Comment: This(http --> https) is not supported as per FAQ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq

Comment: This (http --> https) is now supported by Application Gateway. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-redirect-overview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTTP to HTTPS redirection can now also be configured through the portal. The concept is the same: create a listener for http, then add a rule that redirects to the https listener.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-http-to-https-portal

Comment: This should become the accepted answer now that this functionality is supported through the portal.

Answer (score 13):

**EDIT** ~2019+: Now done via Azure Portal. **See/upvote [Matt Sullivan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57195401/7650275) answer.** Commandline-based approach kept below.

---

Command line approach (like [Jonathan Mast's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45847026/11573842) but with [AZ CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)):

1. Create a listener for your HTTP traffic (e.g. `FE-HTTP-80-Site`). This can be done using Azure portal or CLI.
2. Create a listener for your HTTPS traffic (e.g. `FE-HTTPS-443-Site`). This can be done in the Azure portal or CLI.
3. Create a redirect configuration:

```
az network application-gateway redirect-config create \
--gateway-name AppGateway \
-g RSgroupAppGateway \
-n Redirect-Site-toHTTPS \
--type Permanent \
--include-path true \
--include-query-string true \
--target-listener FE-HTTPS-443-Site
```

3. Create a rule for the HTTP traffic:

```
az network application-gateway rule create \
--gateway-name AppGateway \
-g RSgroupAppGateway \
-n Rule-HTTP-80-Site \
--rule-type Basic \
--http-listener FE-HTTP-80-Site \
--redirect-config Redirect-Site-toHTTPS
```

Reference on Concept: [Create an application gateway with URL path-based redirection using Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-configure-redirect-powershell)

AZ CLI Reference: [Azure Command-Line Interface (CLI) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/)

GUI method (added ~2019+): [Create an application gateway with HTTP to HTTPS redirection using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-http-to-https-portal#add-a-listener-and-redirection-rule)

Comment: Will this work if there is already a rule assigned to the https listener?  It's not possible in the portal anyway...

Comment: I tried it anyway and answered my own question - it does work! +1

Comment: I managed to do the setup with PowerShell based on this Azure shell and Mr. Nagy's PS examples found from http://eduroll.eu/?p=217

Comment: doesn't this mean that people can reach your application gateway on port 80 as well? whereas the point is to allow access to your frontend only on 443

Comment: @naim-salameh Traffic attempting to communicate over port 80 will be redirected to 443. This is helpful because most people don't type: `mywebsite.com:443` - they usually type `mywebsite.com` which will commonly attempt to connect to `mywebsite.com:80`. This is similar to how most domains define a `www` record, allowing users typing "www.mywebsite.com" or "mywebsite.com" to be served, despite the `@` record the only one technically required..

Answer (score 3):

If you handle the redirect on your backend, you can use the **X-Forwarded-Proto** header sent by the App Gateway to see the original request and redirect if it was HTTP using a redirect rule.

### Apache

To do this on Apache, add the following to your *.htaccess* file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

### IIS

Using the IIS [rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) add this to your *web.config* file

```
<rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <rules>
    <rule name="HTTPS rewrite behind App Gw rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}{URL}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is now supported by the Azure Application Gateway product without any additional tools or services.  It is configured using PowerShell as [described in this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-configure-redirect-powershell).

Relevant PoSH code copy and pasted from the reference for redirecting port 80 to 443:

```
# Get the application gateway
$gw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name AdatumAppGateway -ResourceGroupName AdatumAppGatewayRG

# Get the existing HTTPS listener
$httpslistener = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayHttpListener -Name appgatewayhttplistener -ApplicationGateway $gw

# Get the existing front end IP configuration
$fipconfig = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayFrontendIPConfig -Name appgatewayfrontendip -ApplicationGateway $gw

# Add a new front end port to support HTTP traffic
Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayFrontendPort -Name appGatewayFrontendPort2  -Port 80 -ApplicationGateway $gw

# Get the recently created port
$fp = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayFrontendPort -Name appGatewayFrontendPort2 -ApplicationGateway $gw

# Create a new HTTP listener using the port created earlier
Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayHttpListener -Name appgatewayhttplistener2  -Protocol Http -FrontendPort $fp -FrontendIPConfiguration $fipconfig -ApplicationGateway $gw 

# Get the new listener
$listener = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayHttpListener -Name appgatewayhttplistener2 -ApplicationGateway $gw

# Add a redirection configuration using a permanent redirect and targeting the existing listener
Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRedirectConfiguration -Name redirectHttptoHttps -RedirectType Permanent -TargetListener $httpslistener -IncludePath $true -IncludeQueryString $true -ApplicationGateway $gw

# Get the redirect configuration
$redirectconfig = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRedirectConfiguration -Name redirectHttptoHttps -ApplicationGateway $gw


# Add a new rule to handle the redirect and use the new listener
Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -Name rule02 -RuleType Basic -HttpListener $listener -RedirectConfiguration $redirectconfig -ApplicationGateway $gw

# Update the application gateway
Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $gw
```

Comment: I am getting an error Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway : Two Frontend Ports of Application Gateway at last line

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can, only with PowerShell to my knowledge though. The instructions for doing this in ARM are on the [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/application-gateway-ssl-arm/).

I would usually post the instructions here but a number of steps are involved in this, it would be a monster post!

Comment: I actually followed that article, but AFAIK this will not handle redirecting http traffic to https. Could you highlight the step that would implement this?

Comment: You would have to create two listeners, the HTTP one to a server which handles the redirect. It can be same server, however depending on the situation you might want to have them separate. As you have suggested in your post. Apologies - I misunderstood that part of your post, I assumed you wasn't sure if it could do SSL offload.

Comment: I'm hoping to find an alternative as both options feel like workarounds. Not to mention that the separate server (or two, since you would want it load balanced / in an availability set as well) would cost extra money.

Comment: Yep I agree, all I can suggest is logging a suggesting on UserVoice as some product feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer for IIS did not work for me on Win2k16 \ IIS10 and module 2.0; the AG proxy returns an upstream server error; trying to load the rewrite module via IIS manager would result in a malformed XML error.

Removed the insert transform and the redirects started working.

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP To HTTPS Redirect Behind App Gtwy" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}{URL}" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below command and it will work for you

```
$appgw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name GatewayName -ResourceGroupName ResourcegroupName

$myHTTPSListener = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayHttpListener -Name appGatewayHttpListener -ApplicationGateway $appgw

$myHTTPListener = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayHttpListener -Name appGatewayHttpListener -ApplicationGateway $appgw

Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRedirectConfiguration -Name redirectHttptoHttps -RedirectType Permanent  -TargetListener $myHTTPSListener -IncludePath $true -IncludeQueryString $true -ApplicationGateway $appgw

$redirectconfig = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRedirectConfiguration -Name redirectHttptoHttps   -ApplicationGateway $appgw

Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -Name redirectrule -RuleType Basic -HttpListener $myHTTPListener -RedirectConfiguration $redirectconfig  -ApplicationGateway $appgw

Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw
```